Apache PDF Box Fallback Fonts Issue
I'm using PDFBox.
My code triggers the following output:
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Roman with **tabula** which internally uses PDFBox for extraction.

The issue is I'm getting Warning messages for font.
WARNING: Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'MP0001'
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Roman

This is my code:
import tabula
tabula.read_pdf(pdf_file)

Here are my questions:

I'm not sure if this is some font cache building. This is happening for every PDF ran in a loop.
Can these fonts be cached and build only once if possible?
Can someone explain what is going under the hood?

I tried installing apt-get install -q -y libpdfbox-java.

PDFBox adds new fonts to a font cache. If the cache is unwritable or a font is not found, PDFBox uses a fallback font and shows a warning. The font cache location can be controlled by setting the pdfbox.fontcache JVM system property.

I'm using AWS Lambda and Docker, not sure how to do that. An example would be appreciated.

Install the standard 14 fonts on your system. Times roman is one of them.

See also here (not yet on the official site): https://github.com/apache/pdfbox-docs/blob/master/content/2.0/faq.md#what-fonts-do-i-need-on-my-system
